# Database integration with ...well with sound beep or light?

Tags: database

Perhaps this post major editing :

I work for company which sells services online. I would like to build some kind of software bridge/integration tool which would integrate our Oracle database with some sort of device.

We have screens showing live stata like number of items sold, how many are enquiring and similar kind of data. Now it is all fun for executives but I wanted to add extra staff to do.

So when a booking is made in the system and there is INSERT on the booking table new stats are appearing. But for example every 100 orders some sort of bulb lights on. 1000 - Phanfare.

I am not entirely sure what are possible ways of doing it with limited budget. So basically I am looking into software-to-hardware solution.

Any advice,links greatly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this what triggers are for? To trigger an event...

Comment: Consider an Arduino- or Raspberry Pi-based solution, perhaps?

Comment: @DaveRook problem is not coding the trigger. Difficulty is linking it with some sort middle tier communication layer which then talk to something else. Essentially it needs to be three tier  structure: DB, middle tier, hardware at the end.

Comment: You may be able to call a function from a dll - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg11rtn.htm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into products such as this. It's a light indicator that plugs into the USB port.

http://thingm.com/products/blink-1.html

You can find more similar items if you search for "usb light indictator" or something like that.

Comment: Page not found. Can you please provide correct url?